# Schema not Valid after adding ADO.NET entity data model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I just stumbled on an irritating problem. I have an MVC 4 "internet application",
, which has been working fine. I'm using simple membership towards an MSSQL database.

But when I add an "ADO.NET entity data model", the page doesn't load anymore.

I get this error **"EF4.3.1 on .NET 4 - The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type"**

Okay so I googled it and it says two classes can'thave the same name. Okay well then, but I don't have two classes with the same name.

After studying the exception even more I saw that it said that it found a new CLR-Type: UserProfile.. Hmm thats what the simple membership add the first time.

So I went and changed the class name from UserProfile to -> UserProfileDB. Now I can start the page, I can even log in.. But when I run an ordinary query like this:

```
 garView.CustomerList = (List<Models.Databasen.t_customers>)
                       (from x in db.t_customers
                        from y in db.t_customer_guarantee
                        where x.id_kund == y.kundid_garanti
                        select x).ToList();
```

It fails and tells me the relationships is wrong since it can't find UserProfile. I did a complete refactoring Visual Studio did it.

Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved my problem!

1. Delete **all references/files/folder** thats connected to the current entitymodel.
2. Create an **"Empty Project"** name it whatever you like I named mine DatabaseProject
3. Add the **ADO.NET Entity Data model**
4. At the end of the wizard **name the Entities connectionstring to something you remember** i.e (EntityDB)
5. Right click your main project chose **"Add reference"** point it to your new project
6. **Go to app.config** in your "new" project(DatabaseProject) and **copy the (EntityDB)** connectionstring or whatever you named it and **paste it in your web.config** alongside your other connectionstrings
7. Now this one took me a couple of minutes to figure out.... If you build the project now it will fail... Metadata file will be missing for both projects?!
    Well **right click** your new project(DatabaseProject) **choose --> properties**. Make sure the application tab is the one you look at mine starts there yours should aswell, if not choose it's the top left tab. **Then look at output type**, the default for empty project is "ConsoleApplication" no wonder it failed. **Choose --> Class Library**. Press F5 and here you go!